# temporary Table in hql

Tags: sql, hql, temp-tables

my query is like :       `with bigQuery as ( ) select * from bigQuery ;`

how to write it with **HQL** ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. HQL can be used with mapped tables only; you can't use it to create tables on the fly. Use native SQL if you need to do this. further info [HERE](https://coderanch.com/t/427008/databases/temp-hql)